# How to change the attributes of an existing field type table

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to change an attribute (the one witch display the value in browser) of field type table by using addFields() method. The problem is that tables don't have attribute value, they are using some sort of object model. 
I don't know witch attribute name should i use.

I've tried to use ng-model , item.name..

Method:

```
$this->crud->modifyField($name, $modifs_array);
```

My table field:

```
    $this->crud->addField([ // Table
        'name'            => 'options',
        'label'           => 'Options',
        'type'            => 'table',
        'entity_singular' => 'option',
        'model'=>'App\Models\Ticket',
        'columns'         => [
            'name'  => 'Name',
            'price' => 'Price',
        ],
        'max'             => 5, 
        'min'             => 1, 
    ]);
```

Source code from generate field:
  Options

```
<input class="array-json" type="hidden" id="options" name="options">

<div class="array-container form-group">

 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped m-b-0" ng-init="field = '#options'; items = []; max = 5; min = 1; maxErrorTitle = 'Cannot add new option'; maxErrorMessage = 'Maximum number of 5 reached'">
        <thead>
            <tr><th style="font-weight: 600!important;"> Name</th>
            <th style="font-weight: 600!important;"> Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="items" class="table-striped">

            <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="array-row">
                <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="item.name"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="item.price"></td>
                <td ng-if="max == -1 || max > 1"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default sort-handle"><span class="sr-only">sort item</span></tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: Maybe I should fill the imputs using my own method ? Any ideas ?